# jQuery - mousemove : Properly detect on which half of the screen is the cursor

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to detect on which half (left/right) of the screen is the mouse cursor, so I can set a custom cursor accordingly.

Here is my code :

```
var elementHalfWidth = $('#myelement').width() / 2;
// #myelement takes full window

$('#myelement').on('mousemove', function (e) {

    if (e.pageX < elementHalfWidth) {
        $(this).css( 'cursor', 'url(assets/img/cursorL.png), auto' );
    }
    else {
        $(this).css( 'cursor', 'url(assets/img/cursorR.png), auto' );
    }

});
```

HTML :

```
<body><div id="myelement"></div></body>
```

CSS :

```
body {position:relative;}
#myelement {position: absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;}
```

Problem is that the cursor change is triggered on every single mouse move so it's not very efficient (and also cursor flickers a bit from custom to auto, it's probably related).

I can't find a way to trigger the cursor change only when it's needed (ie when the cursor crosses the half of the screen).

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: And CSS too, please?

Comment: Edited with html/css

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand on wich element you're working on, but hope this helps you:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html,body{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).on('mousemove', function(e){
   var lSide=$(this).width()/2;
   var cursorImg=e.pageX<lSide ? 'cursorL' : 'cursorR';
   $('body').css({"cursor":"url('assets/img/"+cursorImg+".png'), auto"});
   console.log(cursorImg) // Just to see check it ;)
  })
</script>
```

Where the **windows** is the screen, and the **body** is the element where you want to show the cursor.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't figure what makes it different from the code in OP ?

Comment: Your element, in this case **#myelement** must have a dimension a width and an height so mousover will have a place to stay **hover** sorry for the word pun ;) Hope this help.

Comment: Another thing is that you wrote: **half (left/right) of the screen is the mouse cursor**, that's why I used the **window** element.